# Подменить в скрипте номера сотовых для  с 89XXXXXXXXX на 79XXXXXXXXX

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Основная задача подменить в скрипте номера сотовых для  с 89XXXXXXXXX на 79XXXXXXXXX

короче решил попробывать поменять через скрипт с дальнейшем выполнением, но не получается регуляркой обработать массив

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $col=>$val){
preg_match("/^[8]{1}[9]{1}[0-9]{9}/", $val, $matches2);
    foreach($matches2 as $col2=>$val2){
        echo"$val2 <hr>";
    }
```

тут показывает всё что надо

пробую менять

```
preg_replace("/^[8]{1}[9]{1}[0-9]{9}/","/^[7]{1}[9]{1}[0-9]{9}/",$string);
```

выдаёт ошибку, мне кажется потому что работает со строкой а меня массив на выходе с базы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

во первых, регулярка у Вас странная. Значительно лучше и правильнее будет такая

```
/^89[0-9]{9}/
```

И соответственно замена будет где то такая

```
preg_replace('/^89([0-9]{9})/','79$1',$string);
```

Comment: так а как сделать что она принимала переменную из массива ?

Comment: уточните вопрос. Куда принимать, как именно, что хочется иметь на выходе.

Answer (score 0):

Касательно массивов и строк можно использовать явное преобразование типов. Регекс, как заметил товарищ выше, странный. Должно быть, у вас мало опыта работы с ними? Как более простой вариант, если это устраивает, можно после преобразования массива в строку зафителить обычную замену символа в строке;